# What data type does a next function return in express and typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

If I remove the void from the response (Response | void) this gives me an error, but I can't put return next () either

```
public async verifyUser(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<Response | void> {
    try {
// do all ...
      next();
    } catch (e) {
      return HttpHandler.response(res, 500, { message: e.message });
    }
```

}

HttpHandler Class

```
import { Response } from 'express';

class HttpHandler {
  /**
   *
   * @param res
   * @param status
   * @param message
   * @param data
   * @returns
   */

      public response(res: Response, status: number, data = {}): Response {
        return res.status(status).json({ result: data });
      }
    }

export default new HttpHandler();
```

Error: *Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.ts(2366)*

Comment: dont mix async and next. And afaik express doesnt await async handler so better dont use async and stick to next.

Comment: Why would you remove `void` as a return type for your middleware?